# How can I type special characters?

Tags: special-characters

I want to type special characters such as `□` and `■`. The problem is, these aren't on my keyboard. What do I do to type them?

It is understood to press Ctrl + Shift + U, but isn't done to press 25a1 after.
I used my left hand to press Ctrl + Shift and right hand to press U.
I can't proceed further.

Comment: In your recent edit, you seem to be saying that since both hands are used to press Ctrl, Shift, and U at the same time, you do not have a free hand available to enter the Unicode hex value. Fortunately, that's not how this text entry method works. Instead, you press Ctrl+Shift+U, then *release all those keys*, then enter the hex code, then press enter. (On the other hand, if that is not what you mean and this does not help, I recommend editing further to clarify the problem. Thanks!)

Comment: Got stressed. What I need is a rest with tourism. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9):

You need the unicode hex values for these as they aren't part of the standard [Compose Key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) lineup. To work out what the keys were, I copied and pasted the characters off your question and stuck them in [this converter](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html). There are many others like it. It gave me the following:

```
U+25A1 : WHITE SQUARE
U+25A0 : BLACK SQUARE
```

To enter these, you follow the standard Unicode entry sequence:

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, unicode hex (in lower case), <kbd>Return</kbd>

□
■

Comment: Alternatively, you can lookup the characters in the GNOME character map tool. It's in the `gucharmap` package.

Comment: You?  Showing up in the low quality queue???  ;-)  That can only be another test...